# Can the matrix exponential be equal to the elementwise exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-sums

Just out of curiosity: does there exist a matrix $A=(a_{i,j}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, n>1$ such that $(e^{a_{i,j}})\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is equal to the matrix exponential $e^A=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{1}{k!}A^k$?

Since for $n=2$ $$\det(e^{a_{i,j}})=e^{a_{11}}e^{a_{22}}-e^{a_{12}}e^{a_{21}}=e^{tr(A)}-e^{a_{12}}e^{a_{21}}=det(e^A)-e^{a_{12}}e^{a_{21}}$$
no $2\times 2$ matrix has this propery. What if $n\geq 3$?

Comment: How does your argument rule out a $2\times 2$ *diagonal* matrix?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: because $\exp 0 =1$...

Comment: oops, right :-)

Comment: $\pmatrix{\ln(-4/3) & \ln(-2) & \ln(-2)\cr
               \ln(-2) & \ln(-4/3) & \ln(-2)\cr
              \ln(-2) & \ln(-2) & \ln(-4/3)}$

Comment: thx, nice example.

Comment: So more generally the matrix with $a$ on diagonal and $b$ on off-diagonal is a solution if $e^{nb}-ne^b+(n-1)=0$ and $e^a=\frac{ne^{2b}}{e^{nb}-1}$.

Comment: Are there any real solutions?

Comment: A real solution can not be of form above since for real $b$ we have $e^{nb}+(n-1)\geq ne^b$ with equality only if $b=0$. But then there is no $a$.

Comment: There seems to be a cyclic solution
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b& c\\ c & a & b\\b & c &a\end{pmatrix}$$
with $(a,b,c)\approx (1.0259,0.9671,-0.1564)$. Found it using the Newton method.

Comment: see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238651/coefficient-wise-powers-of-matrices-reference-wanted