# Coefficient-wise powers of matrices. Reference wanted

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices

Let $K$ be a commutative field and ${\rm M}_n (K)$ be the ring of $n\times n$ square matrices with coefficients in $K$ ($n\geqslant 1$ is an integer). For $k\geqslant 1$ and $A =(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\in {\rm M}_n (K)$, define: $A^{[k]} =(a_{ij}^k )_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$.

> Is the description of all matrices $A\in {\rm M}_n (K)$ satisfying $A^k =A^{[k]}$,  for all $k\geqslant 1$,  known? If yes do you have a reference ?

Comment: See also [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237454/can-the-matrix-exponential-be-equal-to-the-elementwise-exponential). Any such matrix $A$ also answers the question there (about the component-wise exponential).

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether (a) you are looking for a description, or (b) you have found a description but are unsure whether it is already known.  Please clarify.

Comment: I indeed found a description, but wanted to know whether this is known or not.

Comment: @Loïc Not exactly because I want equality for $k\geqslant 1$, not $k\geqslant 0$.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but in searching the literature it may be useful to know that $A^{[k]}$ is called a "Hadamard power" of $A$.

Comment: You want "to describe matrices satisfying this equation for all $k$", or "for all $k$ to describe matrices satisfying this equation"?

Comment: @Fedor The first one.

Comment: @PaulBroussous: granted (I read too fast… of course for $k=0$ you obtain a silly condition), but both questions seem related to me nonetheless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is problem 50.4 by Moubinool Omarjee from [volume 50](http://www.ilasic.org/IMAGE/IMAGES/image50.pdf) of The Bulletin of the International Linear Algebra Society, with solutions in [volume 51](http://www.ilasic.org/IMAGE/IMAGES/image51.pdf) by Eugene Herman and Bojan Kuzma, and further work by Roman Drnovsek in [When powers of a matrix coincide with its Hadamard powers.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00241)

For real matrices the solution is

[image]

Comment: Wonderful !! Thanks a lot Carlo, this is exactly what I was looking for !!